# Helper Data file not loading when I add system payment section

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, helper

I am trying to customize a new payment gateway. Below is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ucs_Najm>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Ucs_Najm>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ucsnajm>
                <class>Ucs_Najm_Model</class>
            </ucsnajm>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <ucsnajm>
                <class>Ucs_Najm_Helper</class>
            </ucsnajm>
        </helpers>  
    </global>
</config>
```

And below is my system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <ucsnajm translate="label" module="ucs_najm">
                    <label>UCS - NAJM</label>
                    <sort_order>110</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                    </fields> 
                </ucsnajm>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Helper Data .php file is located inside app/code/local/Ucs/Najm/Helper

```
<?php
class Ucs_Najm_Helper_Data extends Mage_Payment_Helper_Data {

}
```

But I am getting below error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per as config.xml,you have **define helper class prefix** as *`ucsnajm`*

```
 <helpers>
            <ucsnajm> <!-- called as helper class prefix -->
                <class>Ucs_Najm_Helper</class>
            </ucsnajm>
        </helpers>
```

So,you need to change `module="ucs_najm"` to `module="ucsnajm"` at **system.xml**

Comment: Its working :-) helper class prefix should be called as module?

Comment: No... it always on system.xml if you have call then at module="..." It should be Helper class   prefix.. Please accept the answer